# How to stretch image without looking distorted in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, image, chat, distortion

I am working on chat application and i want to stretch chat bubble image as per text but not getting how to do that.
Please give your suggestion for this matter.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW4

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"chatBubble.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5 topCapHeight:5];
```

This will create an image with the corners 5x5 which doesn't stretch, but with a body that does.